# Problem with new BaseGlobalPlanner plugin

Tags: rrt, base-global-planner, ros-hydro, plugin, ompl

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I tried to make a new BaseGlobalPlanner plugin for use with move_base.
In this Plugin I use ros-hydro-ompl package.

After I've created .cpp and .h (that include ompl library) file, I've compiled with catkin_make and everything works! All the dependencies seem to be satisfied.

But when I run plugin I show this error:

```
[FATAL] [1398764927.385890076, 2.100000000]: Failed to create the ompl_planner_rrt/OMPLPlannerRRT planner, are you sure it is properly registered and that the containing library is built? Exception: Failed to load library /home/prima/catkin_ws/devel/lib//libompl_planner_rrt.so. Make sure that you are calling the PLUGINLIB_EXPORT_CLASS macro in the library code, and that names are consistent between this macro and your XML. Error string: Could not load library (Poco exception = /home/prima/catkin_ws/devel/lib//libompl_planner_rrt.so: undefined symbol: _ZTVN4ompl4base18CompoundStateSpaceE)
```

The name between PLUGINLIB_EXPORT_CLASS macro and XML file is correct!

This is the macro in .cpp file

```
PLUGINLIB_EXPORT_CLASS(ompl_planner_rrt::OMPLPlannerRRT, nav_core::BaseGlobalPlanner)
```

this is .xml file:

```
<library path="lib/libompl_planner_rrt">
  <class name="ompl_planner_rrt/OMPLPlannerRRT" type="ompl_planner_rrt::OMPLPlannerRRT" base_class_type="nav_core::BaseGlobalPlanner">
    <description>
      A implementation of RRT
    </description>
  </class>
</library>
```

The undefined symbol ompl4base18CompoundStateSpace is a ompl function (ompl::base::CompoundStateSpace). It seems that in runtime there aren't dependencies with ompl package.

This is my CMakeLists.txt file:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.3)
project(ompl_planner_rrt)

find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS
  roscpp
  costmap_2d
  geometry_msgs
  nav_core
  nav_msgs
  pluginlib
  tf
  angles
)

find_package(
    ompl
)

find_package(Boost REQUIRED COMPONENTS system thread)
catkin_package(
  INCLUDE_DIRS include
  LIBRARIES ompl_planner_rrt
  CATKIN_DEPENDS roscpp nav_core pluginlib
  DEPENDS system_lib
)

include_directories(
  include
  ${catkin_INCLUDE_DIRS}
)

add_library(ompl_planner_rrt
   src/ompl_planner_rrt.cpp
)

target_link_libraries(ompl_planner_rrt
   ${catkin_LIBRARIES}
   ${OMPL_LIBRARIES} #added on the advice of ahendrix
 )
```

and package.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<package>
  <name>ompl_planner_rrt</name>
  <version>0.0.0</version>
  <description>The ompl_planner package</description>

  <buildtool_depend>catkin</buildtool_depend>
  <build_depend>roscpp</build_depend>
  <build_depend>costmap_2d</build_depend>
  <build_depend>geometry_msgs</build_depend>
  <build_depend>nav_core</build_depend>
  <build_depend>nav_msgs</build_depend>
  <build_depend>pluginlib</build_depend>
  <build_depend>tf</build_depend>
  <build_depend>angles</build_depend>
  <build_depend>eigen_conversions</build_depend>
  <build_depend>boost</build_depend>

  <run_depend>roscpp</run_depend>
  <run_depend>costmap_2d</run_depend>
  <run_depend>geometry_msgs</run_depend>
  <run_depend>nav_core</run_depend>
  <run_depend>nav_msgs</run_depend>
  <run_depend>pluginlib</run_depend>
  <run_depend>tf</run_depend>
  <run_depend>angles</run_depend>
  <run_depend>eigen_conversions</run_depend>
  <run_depend>boost</run_depend>
  <run_depend>ompl</run_depend>


  <export>
     <nav_core plugin="/home/prima/catkin_ws/src/ompl_planner_rrt/bgp_plugin.xml" />
  </export>
</package>
```

When I show this:

```
ldd '/home/prima/catkin_ws/devel/lib/libompl_planner_rrt.so'
```

I don't find libompl.so, I suppose this is the problem.

Can anyone help me? Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/158601/problem-with-new-baseglobalplanner-plugin/) by [Stefano Primatesta](https://answers.ros.org/users/9136/stefano-primatesta/) on ROS Answers with karma: 402 on 2014-04-29

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Ken_in_JAPAN](https://answers.ros.org/users/11311/ken_in_japan/) on 2014-04-29**:
I wanna ask you a question. Did you try `sudo apt-get install ros-hydro-ompl`? I also try it, because I have never installed ompl.

**Comment by [Ken_in_JAPAN](https://answers.ros.org/users/11311/ken_in_japan/) on 2014-04-29**:
I knew you were correct, after installing ompl package . The package included only source.

**Comment by [Stefano Primatesta](https://answers.ros.org/users/9136/stefano-primatesta/) on 2014-04-29**:
I've already install ompl package. I only run sudo apt-get install ros-hydro-ompl, I hope it's enough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It looks like your planner library isn't linked against OMPL.

Try linking it against ompl by adding the following to your CMakeLists.txt:

```
target_link_libraries(ompl_planner_rrt ${ompl_LIBRARIES})
```

(NOTE: this assumes that the find_package command for OMPL is exporting its libraries in the `ompl_LIBRARIES` variable. if it isn't, or the variable name is different, you'll have to make the appropriate adjustments above)

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2014-04-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Stefano Primatesta](https://answers.ros.org/users/9136/stefano-primatesta/) on 2014-04-29**:
I tried to do that, but nothing changes.

**Comment by [Stefano Primatesta](https://answers.ros.org/users/9136/stefano-primatesta/) on 2014-04-29**:
Is there a command to link manually libompl.so? How Can I add libompl.so to my CMakeLists.txt?

**Comment by [Ken_in_JAPAN](https://answers.ros.org/users/11311/ken_in_japan/) on 2014-04-30**:
Hi @Prima89:You executed `sudo apt-get install`  at first. At that time, libompl.so is located in `/opt/ros/hydro/lib` and source file is located in `/opt/ros/hydro/share`. I think so because I tried. So how did you replace the location to `~/catkin_ws/`?

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2014-04-30**:
You can manually link to OMPL with target_link_libraries(ompl_planner_rrt ompl)

**Comment by [Stefano Primatesta](https://answers.ros.org/users/9136/stefano-primatesta/) on 2014-04-30**:
Hi @Ken_in_JAPAN In catkin_ws there is only my package for the plugin. Others packages are in opt/ros/hydro/share with libraries in opt/ros/hydro/lib.

**Comment by [Ken_in_JAPAN](https://answers.ros.org/users/11311/ken_in_japan/) on 2014-04-30**:
@Prima89: Thanks for replying early. I got it. But I don't help you. So sorry!

**Comment by [Stefano Primatesta](https://answers.ros.org/users/9136/stefano-primatesta/) on 2014-05-01**:
Thanks @ahendrix !!! It works, I only add  target_link_libraries(ompl_planner_rrt ompl)

**Comment by [Ken_in_JAPAN](https://answers.ros.org/users/11311/ken_in_japan/) on 2014-05-14**:
Hello @Prima89: I also want to use same plugin with Turtlebot. I'm sorry, but could you show me your *.cpp and *.h?